# IntelliJ Ultimate Unittest throws "ImportError: No module named" for module under test

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, python-unittest

My Python 3 project is organized as follows:

```
/myproject
  /.venv -> stores virtual environment
  /src
    /common
      __init__.py
      utility.py
    /tests
      /common
        __init__.py
        test_utility.py  --> tests utility.py
      __init__.py
    __init__.py
  requirements.txt
```

(The project has many more files and tests, which I've elided for brevity.)

I have this set up in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4. Generally speaking, everything works fine. I have `src` set up as the content root and a virtual environment pointed to use the python libraries in `.venv`, as configured in `requirements.txt`. When I right click on `test_utility.py` in the IDE and select 'Run Unittests...' it executes and runs all the tests, with successes and failures as you'd expect. This also happens if I right click on `common` and select 'Run Unittests...'. However, if I right click on `tests` and do the same all tests report:

```
 ImportError: No module named 'common.utility'
```

The test runner reports it is executing the following:

> Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest discover -s /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests -t /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests in /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests

If I run this in the command line (with the virtual environment on) it also fails. However, if I run this:

> python -m unittest discover -s /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests -t /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src

It succeeds. I don't see a way to tell the IDE to do that, however. Nor does it seem necessary for the other test runs. For instance, this works on the command line:

> python -m unittest discover -s /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests/common -t /Users/nford/repos/myproject/src/tests/common

It is only at this top level that seems to have this problem, meaning that I can't use the IDE to run a complete test run.